# How to sum a variable based on other variables in a table?

Tags: sas

I want to sum the volume variable for each name (TRD_STCK_CD) and date (TRD_EVENT_TM) variables.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
| TRD_EVENT_DT | TRD_EVENT_TM | TRD_STCK_CD | TRD_EVENT_ROUFOR |  VOLUME  |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:01     | ALBZ1       | 12:30            | 15370000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | ALBZ1       | 13:00            |    15670 |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:20:38     | AZAB1       | 12:30            |  6830000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | AZAB1       | 13:00            |     6950 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:14:57      | BALI1       | 9:00             |  7871000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:06      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  1700000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:14      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  8500000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:24      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  5100000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:29:27      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  8500000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:00     | BALIl       | 12:30            |  8500000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:07     | BALIl       | 12:30            |  8500000 |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | BALI1       | 13:00            |     8650 |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
```

I have deleted some col. for simplicity. In next step, I want a table such as below:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
| TRD_EVENT_DT | TRD_EVENT_TM | TRD_STCK_CD | TRD_EVENT_ROUFOR |  VOLUME  | volume_Sum |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:01     | ALBZ1       | 12:30            | 15370000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | ALBZ1       | 13:00            |    15670 |   15385670 |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:20:38     | AZAB1       | 12:30            |  6830000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | AZAB1       | 13:00            |     6950 |    6836950 |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:14:57      | BALI1       | 9:00             |  7871000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:06      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  1700000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:14      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  8500000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:15:24      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  5100000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 9:29:27      | BALI1       | 9:30             |  8500000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:00     | BALIl       | 12:30            |  8500000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 12:28:07     | BALIl       | 12:30            |  8500000 |            |
| 3/24/2008    | 13:13:44     | BALI1       | 13:00            |     8650 |   48679650 |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------+---------
```

Please pay attention to last col. It has been generated by summing volumes that have same TRD_STCK_CD var. So each TRD_STCK_CD obs. has just one Volume_Sum data.

Comment: Can you post the data instead of a photograph? But the photograph does show something strange in the data that might cause trouble. Assuming that this is a photograph of an excel spreadsheet the values `9:30` appear to be text instead of time values since thy are left aligned instead of right aligned in the column.

Comment: I change a photo to the data as Tom mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly different implementation of the same idea:

```
/*Sort by TRD_STCK_CD and temporal variables.*/
proc sort data=have out=have_sorted;
    by  TRD_STCK_CD
        TRD_EVENT_DT
        TRD_EVENT_TM;
run;

/*Sum VOLUME until the last of each TRD_STCK_CD is reached.*/
data want;
    set have_sorted;
    by  TRD_STCK_CD
        TRD_EVENT_DT
        TRD_EVENT_TM;
    retain tmp_volume_sum;
    tmp_volume_sum + VOLUME;
    if last.TRD_STCK_CD then do;
        Volume_Sum = tmp_volume_sum;
        call missing(tmp_volume_sum);
    end;
    drop tmp_:;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I simplified this even more to something with just 2 columns.  The code and the volume.

Here is the sample table creation:

```
data have;
do code = 'a','b','c';
    do i=1 to floor(5*ranuni(1))+1;
        volume = floor(500*ranuni(1));
        output;
    end;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

First use PROC SQL to sum the volume grouped by code.  Save that in a table and put an index on code.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table sums as
select code, sum(volume) as volume_sum
from have
group by code;

create index code on sums;
quit;
```

I assume you have sorted your table by code.  If not, do so.

Now we run through the data we have.  Set the `volume_sum` to null.  If we are on the last record for that code, then look up the value from the `SUMS` table.

```
data want;
set have;
by code;

volume_sum = .;
if last.code then
    set sums key=code;
run;
```

Printed I get:

```
                               code    volume      volume_sum

                                a        485        485
                                b        129          .
                                b        460        589
                                c        271          .
                                c        265          .
                                c         24          .
                                c         33          .
                                c        409       1002
```